# Query nested fields using DSL with elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch

When I try to query a nested field that exists, I didn't get any result (it isn't return any error):

```
                result = es.search(
                          index="mydb", 
                          doc_type="collection", 
                          body={"query": 
                            { 
                                  "term" : {
                                      "foo.bar.field" : value
                                  }
                            }
                          }
                        )
```

NOTE: field is inside bar and bar is inside foo:

```
{ 'topfield' : 23, 'foo' : { 'bar' : { 'field' : 69 }, 'otherfield' : 1}}
```

If I try the same with a field in the top, it works properly:

```
                result = es.search(
                          index="mydb", 
                          doc_type="collection", 
                          body={"query": 
                            { 
                                  "term" : {
                                      "topfield" : value
                                  }
                            }
                          }
                        )
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the query should be as below. i think there is a mismatch in the field bar=>var as seen from the below document.

```
{ 'topfield' : 23, 'foo' : { 'var' : { 'field' : 69 }, 'otherfield' : 1}}
```

Please try the code below

```
            result = es.search(
                      index="mydb", 
                      doc_type="collection", 
                      body={"query": 
                        { 
                              "term" : {
                                  "foo.var.field" : value
                              }
                        }
                      }
                    )
```

could you please confirm on this.

Comment: The problem is the dot sintax, the var/bar it wasn't the problem